# Constantly update tf.cond based on bool value

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conditional-statements

I am using `tf.cond` for controlling the flow of the Tensorflow graph. I went through the documentation and was able to implement `tf.cond` based branching successfully. But my concern is that while the graph is being loaded the value of the `bool` variable is checked and the branching decision is made at the initialization step itself. Any further changes in the `bool` is not tracked. Following is the MWE that better describes the problem:

```py
def funa():
    return tf.constant(32)

def funb():
    return tf.constant(25)

foo = True
x = tf.cond(tf.convert_to_tensor(foo), lambda: funa(), lambda: funb())
for i in range(20):
    global foo
    if i > 10:
        foo = False
    print(sess.run(x))
```

This prints only `32`s.

I tried with `eager_execution` too with the following code:

```py
tf.enable_eager_execution()
def funa():
    return tf.constant(32)

def funb():
    return tf.constant(21)

foo = True
x = tf.cond(tf.convert_to_tensor(foo), lambda: funa(), lambda: funb())
for i in range(20):
    if i > 10:
        foo = False
    print(x)
```

Still the same result.

So my question is how can I write code such that one part of the graph is chosen dynamically, based on the updates to the `bool` variable (if possible)? Thanks. I am using Tensorflow v1.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a placeholder for `foo` and feed it's value while running the session. Modified code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def funa():
    return tf.constant(32)

def funb():
    return tf.constant(25)

foo = True
foo_p = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

sess = tf.Session()

x = tf.cond(foo_p, lambda: funa(), lambda: funb())
for i in range(20):
    if i > 10:
        foo = False
    print(sess.run(x, {foo_p:foo}))
```

Comment: So straight forward, wonderful. Did not think about using `placeholder`, thanks.